# How to configure sublimelinter per folder

Tags: sublimetext2, jshint, sublimelinter

Is it possible to configure sublimelinter to check specific folders with specific settings.

For starters I would like to use it for js files using the "javascript_linter" : "jshint" and have "jshint_options" set for different folders

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [Per-Project Settings](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter#per-project-settings) in the README, you'll see how to set SublimeLinter up to search different paths for different projects. For more help on projects, [read the docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html).

Comment: I don't think that it was a question about per-project settings but rather per-folder ones: "have "jshint_options" set for different folders".